# Where to put the try catch block

Tags: java, switch-statement, try-catch, hashset

Good morning everyone... I am wondering where to put the try-catch block for not integer Input(InputMismatchException) to work in this code,
If I put it here doesn't work, if I put it before while, it's an infinite loop,  if you can explain where and why  it will be perfect, thank you for your time.

```
public void additionalIngredients() {
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
    boolean flag = false;
    while (!flag) {
        System.out.println("Enter your choice for extra toppings ");
        int choices = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine();
        try {
            switch (choices) {
                case 0:
                    System.out.println("Done");
                    flag = true;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    if (!set.contains(choices)) {
                        double extraSauce = 1.2;
                        setAdditionalStuff(getAdditionalStuff() + extraSauce);
                        System.out.println("Extra sauce added on your pizza \n");
                        break;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("You already added extra sauce, please consider to add something else");
                        break;
                    }
                case 2:
                    if (!set.contains(choices)) {
                        double extraCheese = 2.3;
                        setAdditionalStuff(getAdditionalStuff() + extraCheese);
                        System.out.println("Extra cheese added on your pizza \n");
                        break;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("You already added extra cheese, please consider to add something else");
                        break;
                    }
                case 3:
                    if (!set.contains(choices)) {
                        double largeDough = 0.7;
                        setAdditionalStuff(getAdditionalStuff() + largeDough);
                        System.out.println("Your pizza has a large Dough \n");
                        break;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Your pizza has already a large dough, consider something else");
                        break;
                    }
            }

            set.add(choices);
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Please enter an integer!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should include getting input from user within the try block `try{ int choices = scanner.nextInt(); ...}`

Comment: Still infinite loop, I think I have to check from the start if my input is an integer or not, what the guy said down, using another method for that.

Comment: include your `scanner.nextLine();` in catch block

Answer (score 1):

There are may ways to go about this. Always strive for solutions that make your code easier to read and understand.

One way to do that: you could for example create another helper method `fetchSelectionFromUser()` that does **one** thing only: loop (with try catch) until the user entered a **valid** number.

One guiding rule is the [single layer of abstraction](http://principles-wiki.net/principles:single_level_of_abstraction) principle. And that tells you that having a-switch-in-a-try-in-a-loop isn't the way to go. As said, you could go for a loop that simply calls two methods: one that fetches the input, and another one that processes it.

Comment: uuu got it, thank you, I am gonna try that.

Comment: @Florin123 You are very welcome. Please consider to upvote and/or accept at some point in case you find it helpful "enough" ;-)